# Hadoop combiner : Using same reducer code as combiner in a word count mapreduce program?

Tags: hadoop, word-count, combiners

This question from the certification body's practice test in particular, does not make sense to me. Can anyone help ?

Question :
Word count problem with mapper emitting key and value pairs where for each word as key, literal 1 is emitted as the value.Then the reducer increments a counter for each literal "1" it receives. The qn is "Can we use the existing reducer code as the combiner"?

The correct answer is depicted as. "YES" , we can since the sum task is commutative and associative.

But my understanding is that, the answer should be "NO" as the two scenario results in two diff answers. And I believe same reducer and combiner code can be only used if instead of "increasing a counter for each literal 1 it receives", we employ another approach of increasing the counter by the value it receives.

Considering it with a example
lets consider a hypothetical case without combiner first
e.g suppose map1 o/p be (to,1), (to,1) and map2 o/p be (to,1)
then i/p to reducer becomes (to, [1,1,1])
the reducer o/p then becomes (to,3)

But with combiner, when map1 o/p is fed to combiner then the combiner o/p becomes (to,2). The reducer i /p now becomes (to, [2,1]). Then in reducer, we increment counter only and only for each literal 1 value  i.e we discard the literal 2 and the o/p then becomes (to,1)

With combiner the o/p is (to,1) and without combiner we see that the o/p is (to,3).

Please help me, if I am wrong somewhere with this or if its otherwise ?

Thanking you in advance for your answers,
Bikal Basnet

Comment: Sounds like whoever wrote the practice test needs some practice of his/her own

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, however in classic MapReduce word count application, reducer can be used as combiner. Take a look at line 37 in [WordCount](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount). It is:

```
sum += val.get();
```

And not:

```
sum += 1;
```

Comment: Totally agree with you on this for the classic map reduce program. But the practice question  considers the later case , sum += 1, and argues for using reducer as combiner.  I was confused there. Thanks anyway